# Angular 6 [ngclass] - add a class which is name is composed by several variables - string concatenation on [ngClass] directly

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm using angular 6. Taking the following variables as an example:

```
var1 = 'my';
var2 = '-';
var3 = 'class';
```

How can I do something like this:

```
<div [ngClass]='var1 + var2 + var3'></div>
```

Expecting that the HTML produced looks like this:

```
<div class='my-class'></div>
```

**[Edit]**

I know that is possible to use a auxiliary function in order to get the class name like this:

```
getClassName(): {
 return var1 + var2 + var3;
}

<div [ngClass]='getClassName()'></div>
```

But what I really want is a way to do that directly on the html using angular

Comment: What you expecting ?? concatenation??

Comment: Did you read that? https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Comment: What's not working? You can do that. Just change `ngclass` to `ngClass`

Comment: @iamrajshah I made editions to my post to became more clear what I'm asking

Comment: @sjahan Yes, and does not seams to have my case

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner Yes, you have right, but I was just trying to give an example what I pretend to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there is a lot ways to do so. I would recommend something like this:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xtwwwi

Hope this helps.

EDIT. You can always pass an array to function, and then return string. My example is just raw example of how ngClass works. Also your method will work too:

```
[ngClass]="var1 + var2 + var3"
```

Comment: It works, but I want a way to make the string concatenation directly on the html instead of using a auxiliary function

Comment: @RicardoRocha Just check my edit :) (also stackblitz is updated)

Answer (score -2):

You should use string interpolation:

```
<div [ngClass]="`${var1 + var2 + var3}`">
```

Comment: Won't work. But `{{ var1 + var2 + var3 }}` should though.

Comment: @trichetriche non of the solutions provided seams to work